# chmod 070 allows all but owner of file to wrx

Tags: permissions, group, chmod

Directory permissions:

```
d---rwx---   2 root  wheel     -       512 Aug  5 15:43 Test/
```

File permsisions:

```
----rwx---   1 chambi  wheel  -   33 Aug  5 15:42 loop.py*
```

Both the directory and file only allow those in group wheel to wrx. In this case however, it seems to be all within group wheel other than the owner of the file "chambi". Why is this the case? This issue can be overcome if I create the file as root but I want users within this group to be able to make files under their own names and be able to edit, execute etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File permissions aren’t cumulative](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276313/86440), the most specific permission applies. If you want the owner of a file as well as group members to be able to access it, the appropriate permission is 770.