# ls throws errors when trying to access directory guarded with ACL

Tags: permissions, setfacl

I have setup a directory and some files with setfacl.

```
jobq@workstation:~/Pool$ getfacl /etc/jobq
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: etc/jobq
# owner: root
# group: jobq
user::rwx
user:jobq:rw-
group::r-x
group:jobq:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x

jobq@workstation:~/Pool$ sudo getfacl /etc/jobq/log.txt
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: etc/jobq/log.txt
# owner: root
# group: jobq
user::rw-
group::rw-
group:jobq:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--

jobq@workstation:~/Pool$ groups
jobq
```

However, when I run a command, like

```
ls -al /etc/jobq
```

I'm getting permission errors:

```
ls: cannot access '/etc/jobq/log.txt': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
```

Since user `jobq` is in the group `jobq`, they should have access to the directory. What am I misunderstanding? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from this ACL on `/etc/jobq`:

```
user:jobq:rw-
```

This means that user `jobq` can’t “search” the directory, which is what stops `ls` from showing its contents.

To fix this, you need to add the `x` permission. See [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/86440) for details.

See also [Restrictive "group" permissions but open "world" permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276306/86440) to understand why the group permissions don’t help here. Thus another solution would be to drop the user ACL for `jobq`, and rely on the group permissions instead.